# pyodbc insert into sql server Error 42000

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am using python 3.8 64 bit on windows with pyodbc 4.0.3 with {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}

The destination is sql server 2017. The target database table column is with collation 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8'

The target table structure is
ID INT
CONTENTS VARCHAR(MAX)

While trying insert into the target table with a value longer than 8000 characters, getting the following error.
`Error while loading records in sql table tbl1 ('42000',"[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server] Can not convert to text/ntext or collate to 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8' because these legacy LOB types do not support UTF-8 or UTF-16 encodings. Use types Varchar(max), nvarchar(max) or a collation which does not have the _SC or _UTF8 Flags`

The Trace on SQL Side shows the following

```
  declare @p1 int
  exec sp_prepare @p1 output, N'@P1 int,@P2 ntext',N' insert into tbl1 (ID,CONTENTS) VALUES (@P1,@P2),1
  ...
```

how can i change the parameter value @P2 to VARCHAR(MAX) ?
i tried by changing the `cursor.setinputsizes([(pyodbc.SQL_VARCHAR,0,0)])`   but still the same error is fired.

Comment: Have you seen [Cannot insert strings with a length greater than 2000 into columns with a datatype of varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) using parametrised queries #835](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/835) yet? Seems like pyodbc needs changes to better support n/varchar(max) data types.

Comment: Try applying `setinputsizes` to the *second* parameter: `cursor.setinputsizes([None, (pyodbc.SQL_VARCHAR,0,0)])`

Comment: Hi did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue with pyodbc.